# how do I capture point in arbitrary file as orgmode external file link?

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

I had this once upon a time but I have misplaced the bit that did it.  In an arbitrary file at point I want to make an external file orgmode link that sticks around long enough to paste elsewhere.  I am sure someone did this before as I used to have it.  But alas, I have misplaced it.

Comment: You don't mean `org-store-link`, `org-insert-link`? What do you mean by _link that sticks around long enough to paste elsewhere_?

Comment: Exactly.  I had such a thing once upon a time that I saw on one such emacs list as this.  But I have misplaced it.  One command created the link at the point in the file where my cursor was.  Then I would move to my org file to paste it in and be prompted to chose which with the default being the most recent.  I would get a prompt to give it a label (second part of mypellink).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `org-store-link` to store the position of your current emacs buffer file and in your org file `org-insert-link` to insert the stored link. This prompts you with a selection of links and a query for the description to insert.

Comment: It is often recommended to bind `org-store-link` to `C-c l`, since `org-insert-link` is bound to `C-c C-l` by default.

Comment: Thanks!  And here I was thinking it was more complicated.